# 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR' on Sequelize Node.JS

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

My config code:

```
    const { DataTypes, Model } = require('sequelize')

module.exports = class Configs extends Model {
    static init(sequelize) {
        return super.init({
            guildId: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                primaryKey: true,
            },
            guildName: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
            },
            statsId: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
            },
            statsOn: {
                type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
            }
        }, {
            tableName: 'Configs',
            sequelize
        })
    }
}
```

My index code:

```
 fetchChn.fetch()

    if (fetchChn) {
          const configs = await Configs.create({
              guildId: message.guild.id,
              statsId: statschannel,
              statsOn: true,
          });
          console.log(configs);
```

I'm trying to put "true" when an user sends the ID of Channel (Discord.JS v12), but i get:

```
 code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
    errno: 1054,
    sqlState: '42S22',
    sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'statsOn' in 'field list'",
    sql: 'INSERT INTO `Configs` (`guildId`,`statsId`,`statsOn`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);',
    parameters: [
      '857470261346304011',
      '860215963105755157',
      true,
      '2021-07-01 18:12:56',
      '2021-07-01 18:12:56'
    ]
  },
  sql: 'INSERT INTO `Configs` (`guildId`,`statsId`,`statsOn`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);',
  parameters: [
    '857470261346304011',
    '860215963105755157',
    true,
    '2021-07-01 18:12:56',
    '2021-07-01 18:12:56'
  ]
}
```

Into the model code I created "statsOn", and I try to add it manually on heidiSQL but it doesn't works too.